# Need help with an essay question related to chemical engineering (High School)

Tags: chemical-engineering

I have to do an essay question related to an area of my choice (Chemical Engineering). Could anyone suggest an area of research that is accessible to a High Schooler within ChemEng?

Thank You

Comment: Fermentation is a broad subject that could given some idea for an essay.

Comment: Petroleum refining

Answer (score 1):

The development of the Haber process, which allowed for manufacture of solid nitrogen for fertilizer in the early 20th century could be a topic of research.